# When I compile a c++ project, I have no problem on my own computer. Now, I switch to the cloud server and an error occurs

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

This is part of the error message, mainly about stl, and the part that is not shown is similar.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o server main.c ./threadpool/threadpool.h ./http/http_conn.cpp ./http/http_conn.h ./lock/locker.h ./log/log.cpp ./log/log.h ./CGImysql/sql_connection_pool.cpp ./CGImysql/sql_connection_pool.h -lpthread -lmysqlclient -lstdc++
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_iterator.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/list:60,
                 from ./threadpool/threadpool.h:4,
                 from main.c:13:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/ptr_traits.h:119:71: error: macro "static_assert" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
    "pointer type defines element_type or is like SomePointer<T, Args>");
                                                                       ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/list:63,
                 from ./threadpool/threadpool.h:4,
                 from main.c:13:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_list.h:577:62: error: macro "static_assert" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
    "std::list must have a non-const, non-volatile value_type");
                                                              ^
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_list.h:580:62: error: macro "static_assert" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
    "std::list must have the same value_type as its allocator");
                                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_iterator.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/list:60,
                 from ./threadpool/threadpool.h:4,
                 from main.c:13:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/ptr_traits.h:119:72: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘;’ token
    "pointer type defines element_type or is like SomePointer<T, Args>");
                                                                        ^
                                                                        (
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/ptr_traits.h:119:72: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/ptr_traits.h:118:20: error: expected ‘,’ before ‘;’ token
       static_assert(!is_same<element_type, __undefined>::value,
                    ^
                    ,
    "pointer type defines element_type or is like SomePointer<T, Args>");
                                                                        ~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/ptr_traits.h:119:72: error: expected string-literal before ‘;’ token
    "pointer type defines element_type or is like SomePointer<T, Args>");
                                                                        ^
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/ptr_traits.h:118:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
       static_assert(!is_same<element_type, __undefined>::value,
                    ^
                    )
    "pointer type defines element_type or is like SomePointer<T, Args>");
```

`from ./threadpool/threadpool.h:4,`  corresponds to

```
#include <list>
```

g++ version of this cloud server

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --disable-libmpx --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-4) (GCC)
```

I have tried to change the g++ version through devtoolset, but it is still to no avail and the error is similar.

Comment: "macro "static_assert" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2" It seems that the compiler on your cloud server implements `static_assert` as a macro and you pass a condition that contains a comma in a template argument list. This unfortunately breaks some macros, because the preprocessor does not recognize matching `<` and `>` tokens as brackets. Try to wrap the condition expression in parantheses.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't understand "Try to wrap the condition expression in parantheses". I don't use static_assert in my code. Do you mean changes to the condition expression in static_assert in the stl source file?

Comment: I see, I thought the static assert was in your code. Are you perhaps using some library that defines a `static_assert` macro?

Comment: It seems unlikely, since most of what this project introduces is system library files and mysql. There aren't too many other libraries.

Comment: One thing I would suspect is that somewhere the C11 `static_assert` macro from the <assert.h> header leaks into the code. That seems very painful. Can you post the line with the static assert from the STL source file?

Comment: If the code is supposed to be C++, I wouldn't use `.c` as the file extension.

Comment: @BoP Good catch! That might explain the issue

Comment: Thank you for your advice.@BoP @chrysante  Yesterday, I combed through the project again and finally found the problem, which is the macro pollution mentioned before. include <assert.h>; There is a file under /usr/local/include/ that redefines static_cast                                                                                                              
`#ifndef _FIXUP_ASSERT_H
#define _FIXUP_ASSERT_H

#include_next <assert.h>

/* Without C11 compiler support it is not possible to implement static_assert */
#undef static_assert
#define static_assert(_cond, msg)

#endif`

Comment: I don't understand why there is such a file here. When I block this section, the project will compile normally.

Comment: @大鸡啄米mm Have you changed the filename from "main.c" to "main.cpp"? That macro is part of the C-standard.

Comment: No, I didn't modify the file extension.